# java integer color to flutter color and back

Tags: java, flutter

I'm rebuilding my app from java to flutter. I'm using firebase to store colors as integer values. In java I can use the following to convert rgb values to integer values:

```
colorInt = (255 << 24) | (color.red << 16) | (color.green << 8) | color.blue;
```

And I can use the following to convert from an integer value to rgb:

```
int r = (colorInt >> 16) & 0xFF;
int g = (colorInt >> 8) & 0xFF;
int b = colorInt & 0xFF;
```

How can I convert a Java integercolor to a flutter color and back?

An example, lets take RGB 154, 255, 147

In flutter this would be the result is 4288348051

```
(255 << 24) | (154 << 16) | (255 << 8) | 147;
(4278190080) | (10092544) | (65280) | 147;

(4278190080) | (10092544) = 4288282624;
(4278190080) | (10092544) | (65280) = 4288347904;
(4278190080) | (10092544) | (65280) | 147 = 4288348051
```

In java this would be -6619245

```
(255 << 24) | (154 << 16) | (255 << 8) | 147;
(-16777216) | (10092544) | (65280) | 147;

(-16777216) | (10092544) = -6684672;
(-16777216) | (10092544) | (65280) = -6619392;
(-16777216) | (10092544) | (65280) | 147 = -6619245;
```

Comment: Bitwise `or` and `and` and shifts still exist - https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/int-class.html#operators

Comment: Do you have an example? `print('${2 | 1}')` shows me 3, as expected

Comment: @cricket_007see my edit

Comment: Dart uses 64 bit integers, so if you change your Java code to using a `long` instead of an `int` you'll get the same (positive) result. You are getting a negative number in Java because you are putting a 32 bit int with the top bit set into an int, which are signed in Java. Naturally, they are all the same bit pattern, just printed differently depending in whether the container is signed.

Comment: That is not an option. That requires all my users to re-enter their data.

Comment: you see the results man! only the upper parts changing- so do something about it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, as @Ovidiu mentioned, Java uses signed 32 bit integers. Expanding on the code block they posted, we can create a full example which gives us what we need:

```dart
import 'dart:math';

int chopToJavaInt (int result) {
  while (result > pow(2, 31)) {
    result = result - pow(2, 32);
  }
  return result;
}

int javaIntColor(int r, int g, int b) {
  var x = (g << 24) | (r << 16) | (g << 8) | b;
  return chopToJavaInt(x);
}

void main () {
  print(javaIntColor(154, 255, 147)); //-6619245
}
```

This solution is modular, maintains your original style from your Java code, and will return the correct value.

Comment: What about converting the java int color to dart material Color ?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe fill high-order digits with ones?

```dart
    int rgb = -6619245;
    final c = Color(rgb);
    print('${c.red} ${c.green} ${c.blue}');
    int fromColorRgb = c.value | 0xFFFFFFFF00000000;
    print('$rgb : $fromColorRgb');
```

Result:

```
I/flutter (10689): 154 255 147
I/flutter (10689): -6619245 : -6619245
```

Assuming your alpha channel is always 255

Answer (score 1):

Java is using signed 32 bit int, so values are between -2^31 and 2^31. Once they reach 2^31, they continue from -1 towards -2^31.

Try applying this on the result you get in Flutter:

```
if (result > pow(2, 31)) {
  result = result - pow(2, 32);
}
```